# Java Interactive CLI Option Prompt

Tags: java

Is there a way to implement an interactive cli that allows you to select from multiple options?

I want to achieve something like the following:

[image: Interactive CLI creates using inquirer.js]

The example shown is implemented using the inquirer.js library in JavaScript, but I can’t seem to find a way to implement something similar in Java.

Comment: It is not possible out of the box in Java. So you'd have to do it using JNI, either directly or by using a specific library that would do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ncurses-like libraries available for Java: [JavaCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) and [Charva](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/) and maybe more.

What you have there in the picture looks like it may be implemented with [JList](https://github.com/rbalint/charva/blob/master/java/src/charvax/swing/JList.java) for example.